# Different behavior when running code from file then when running it from shell

Tags: python, apache-kafka

I'm learning how to use kafka under python.

I have kafka server running and a consumer that is listening on `mytopic`.

Now i wrote this piece of code using `confluent-kafka`:

```
from confluent_kafka import Producer
p = Producer({'bootstrap.servers': 'localhost:9092'})
p.produce('mytopic', key='hello', value='world')
```

when i run `python` and paste that code it works (consumer is collecting)

however if save it to `example.py`and run `python example.py` it does not.

Anyone understand this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you run your code from a file, it terminates immediately after the last line.

To wait for the producer to have sent all messages before closing, you need to call `flush()`:

```
p.flush()
```

See the API docs: https://docs.confluent.io/current/clients/confluent-kafka-python/index.html#confluent_kafka.Producer.flush